# Как правильнее использовать потоки в Python?

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

Следующая проблема:
Программа состоит из окна авторизации и главного окна, на которой отображен флаг соединения с удаленным сервером
При инициализации главного окна создается поток, пингующий сервер, в случае неудачи изменяет значение флага и на протяжении 30 секунд пробует переподключиться. Если не получается - отображает сообщение об ошибке и возвращает на окно авторизации. Так было задумано, но получается, что после отображения сообщения об ошибке и закрытие главного окна программа зависает
Как в такой ситуации правильно спроектировать отдельный поток?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Занесите нужные вам фрагменты кода в функции. Допустим:

```
def flag():
    #тут ваш код, проверяющий флаг
```

```
from threading import Thread
#ваш код
#перед началом самой программы пишите:
Thread(target=flag).start()
#ваша программа
```

Что это даёт: поток выполняется, даже если код стоит на каком-нибудь input.

Большее вы можете узнать из документации `threading`

---

Всем добра-бобра